# JQGrid columns reorder

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, remap

I've tried to use `remapColumns`:

```
grid.remapColumns(newOrder, false, false);
```

but got a strange issue - column headers was reordered, but column infos stayed untouched. How can solve that?

EDIT:

Whole mthod

```
permutateGrid: function (gridID, columnsToShow, columnsToHide) {
    var newOrder = [];
    var grid = $(gridID);

    for (var i = 0; i < columnsToShow.length; i++) {
        newOrder.push(GridHelpers.getColumnSrcIndexByName(grid, columnsToShow[i]));
    }

    var columnsCount = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < columnsCount; i++) {
        if (newOrder.indexOf(i) === -1) {
            newOrder.push(i);
        }
    }

    showColumns(gridID, columnsToShow);
    hideColumns(gridID, columnsToHide);

    grid.jqGrid('remapColumns', newOrder, false, false);
    grid[0].jqGrid().updateColumns();
},
```

Comment: What you mean under "column infos"? What exactly is wrong? Do you use `newOrder` array which has the same length as `colModel`?

Comment: Column infos is a column contents. `newOrder` has the same lengths as 'colModel', see EDIT

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? I don't know `updateColumns`. It doesn't exist in jqGrid now. Moreover I still don't understand what problem you have. What is "column contents"? Do you mean the column headers of the columns of the grid? When and where you call `permutateGrid` function (for example in empty grid, inside of some callback etc)

Comment: I removed `updateColumn` string because there is no such function. I'm using jqGrid version 4.4.1. I'm calling `permutateGrid` from callback for grid with some information, and then calling 'reloadGrid'. And the problem is following: ONLY column HEADERS are reordered after these actions.

Comment: @Oleg: the wiki (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) still lists the updateColumns method, that's probably where the confusion is coming from.  See also this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191543/how-to-fix-sync-issue-between-column-header-width-and-column-body-width-without) and this post on the jqGrid forum (http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/updatecolumns-deprecated-in-3-8-is-there-a-replacement-to-fix-header-widthing-issue-1/#p29770), which led me here.

Comment: @mcw0933: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. If you have some suggestion how to improve wiki documentation of jqGrid you can do this like every other person. You need just register on the wiki and make the changes which you mean should be done. The owner of the wiki (trirand and not me) can revert the changes or improve there. I have no relation to trirand. [Your post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/updatecolumns-deprecated-in-3-8-is-there-a-replacement-to-fix-header-widthing-issue-1/#p29770) seems to me describes **absolutely another problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `remapColumns` should be `true` if you want to update grid content. Typical usage of `remapColumns` is `grid.jqGrid("remapColumns", newOrder, true, true);` (or `grid.remapColumns(newOrder, true);`).

Comment: Is that ethod suitable for grid with subgrids?

Comment: My problem was following - I've tryed to remap all the column including `subgrid` - but it have to stay at `0` index

Comment: @skayred: I would recommend you to include screenshort next time. It would clear many things. Additionally more full JavaScript code with jqGrid parameters are required in the most cases.